# How to throw html input values into ng-click function with angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Hello guys i am learning html and angularjs at the same time.I don't know how i can throw simple input into my functions.

Random

`<input id="input1" type="text">`

`<button ng-click="someAction()">click me</button>`

Basically i want to put the text value from the input into someAction method. Sorry if my code or question is confusing. It confuses me too.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to use [ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) and [$scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) to save the function

```js
angular.module('starter', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.someAction = function(name) {
      $scope.result = 'Hi ' + name;
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.8.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="starter" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <!-- ngModel will store the input data, it's as if you were creating a variable -->
  <input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Your name"/>
  <button ng-click="someAction(name)">Some action</button>
  <p>{{result}}</p>
</div>
```